# Mocking an AWS ScheduledEvent class using C# .NET

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentvalidation, aws-event-bridge, fakeiteasy

I am trying to verify that data coming in the `Detail` property of an AWS `ScheduledEvent` object is correct.  The information should be coming in from `EventBridge` with JSON in the `Detail` property that matches this class:

```
public class EventBatchData
{
    public int BatchSize { get; private set; }
    public int BatchRetries { get; private set; }

    public EventBatchData(int batchSize, int batchRetries)
    {
        BatchSize = batchSize;
        BatchRetries = batchRetries;

        var validator = new EventBatchDataValidator();
        validator.ValidateAndThrow(this);
    }
}
```

I have a `FluentValidation` validator in the class so it cannot be created in an invalid state.

However, I am not able to set the `SceduledEvent.Detail` property, either directly or as an expectation through a mocking library.  The `Detail` property is defined with type `T` so I even tried using `dynamic` but that fails:

```
[Theory]
    [AutoFakeItEasyData]
    public void NotThrowError_WhenDetailIsValid(EventBatchData eventBatchData)
    {
        //Arrange
        dynamic expectedDetail = new ExpandoObject();
        expectedDetail.BatchRetries = eventBatchData.BatchRetries;
        expectedDetail.BatchSize = eventBatchData.BatchSize;

        var scheduledEvent = new ScheduledEvent
        {
            Account = "testAccount",
            Region = "testRegion",
            DetailType = "Scheduled Event",
            Source = "aws.events",
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Id = "cdc73f9d-aea9-11e3-9d5a-835b769c0d9c",
            Resources = new List<string> { "resource1", "resource2" },
            Detail = expectedDetail
        };

        //Act
        var result = _validator.TestValidate(scheduledEvent);

        //Assert
        result.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Detail);
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to 'Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents.ScheduledEvents.Detail'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScheduledEvent` class actually inherits from the `CloudWatchEvent<Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents.ScheduledEvents.Detail>` class, so the `Details` field is not a generic data type; instead, it is type of `Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents.ScheduledEvents.Detail` class.

Hence, you cannot use the `dynamic` data type for the `Details` field; instead, convert the `EventBatchData` class to the `Details` data type, and it should work.

```
public class EventBatchData : Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents.ScheduledEvents.Detail 
{
    public int BatchSize { get; private set; }
    public int BatchRetries { get; private set; }

    public EventBatchData(int batchSize, int batchRetries)
    {
        BatchSize = batchSize;
        BatchRetries = batchRetries;

        var validator = new EventBatchDataValidator();
        validator.ValidateAndThrow(this);
    }
}
```