# Why is AWS EventBridge Detail null?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

Following up on a question I asked previously: [Mocking an AWS ScheduledEvent class using C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540858/mocking-an-aws-scheduledevent-class-using-c-sharp-net)

I have setup an EventBridge (EB) rule that runs every 5 minutes and targets a Lambda that ingests JSON data from the EB rule.  The JSON is very simple:

```
{
  "BatchSize": 10,
  "BatchRetries": 3
}
```

My target Lambda is in C# 6 .NET and has a class for deserializing the data:

```
public class EventBridgeDetailDto : Detail
{
    public int BatchSize { get; set; }
    public int BatchRetries { get; set; }
}
```

My Lambda's handler looks like so:

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent, ILambdaContext context){
}
```

My understanding is that the JSON from the EB event would be in `scheduledEvent.Detail` but that property is always null.  What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure the lambda to be triggered by the `EventBridge` scheduler every 5 minutes, using a custom payload, then the lambda function will only receive the custom payload object. Note that, the lambda function will receive `CloudWatchEvent<T>` events only when those events are published via the `EventBus`.

In your scenario, you directly consume the payload from the scheduler, not from the `EventBus`. So you have to use your `EventBridgeDetailDto` class directly to consume the payload.

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(EventBridgeDetailDto payload, ILambdaContext context){
}
```

Also, there is no need to inherit your `EventBridgeDetailDto` class from the `Detail` data type, as it is not applicable to your use case.

```
public class EventBridgeDetailDto
{
    public int BatchSize { get; set; }
    public int BatchRetries { get; set; }
}
```